# jQuery: How to get count of a filled form elements

Tags: jquery

I've a filter elements as shown in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/S8FK3/3/).

Is it possible to show count of user selected filters beside the **Filters link** ?

Note: In my case filter elements are dynamic,So its not possible to use elements id or name as a selector,but `<div class="filtersDiv">` is static.

**Update:**

Even form elements are dynamic,elements name will start with `user_`,modified [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/S8FK3/4/),hope this might help in solving the issue.

Answer (score 1):

hey have updated you fiddle

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/S8FK3/7/)

Code Here

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on('click',"a#filters",function(e)
    {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("div.filtersDiv").toggle('slow');
    });
    var count=0;
    $('input:checkbox').on('change', function(){ 
     if($(this).is(':checked')){
            count +=1;
        }else{
           count -=1; 
        }
        $("#countid").html(count);
    });
    $('input[name=user_gender]').on('change', function(){
       $("#countid").html(count += 1);
        $('input[name=user_gender]').unbind('change');
     });  
   $('input[type=text]').blur(function(){
       if($.trim($(this).val()) !=''){
        count +=1;   

       }else{
         count -=1;              
       }
    $("#countid").html(count);   
   }); 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a span underneath your filter anchor

```
<a href="#" id="filters">Filters</a>
<span id="count"></span>
```

And add this handler in your `$(document).ready()` handler

```
$('.filtersDiv').on('keyup focus blur change', ':input', function(){
    var num_of_active_filters =  $(":text[value!=''], :file, :checkbox:checked, select, textarea, :radio:checked").length;
    $('#count').text(num_of_active_filters)
});
```